# CGRectIntersectsRect... Determine side of the UIImageView the intersect happened on?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

How could I detect, not only if the frames of two images intersect, but the side in which the intersect happened on? Was the imageview touched on its left side, or right side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get both `CGRects` that intersected, and get their respective frames, and then determine by their position where they are at.